# comparing lists in python, with a twist

Tags: python, string, list

So I have two lists I want to compare, listA and listB.  If an item from listA appears in listB, I want to remove it from listB.  I can do this with:

```
listA = ["config", "\n", "config checkpoint"]
listB = ["config exclusive", "config checkpoint test", "config", "config", "config", "\n", "hello"]
    
listB = [line for line in listB if not any(line in item for item in listA)]
```

But where things now become more complex, is that I have some lines I want to remove only if the list item matches exactly (as it currently does), but also lines that I want to remove if the item from listB contains the item from listA, i.e. a partial match.

I'm not sure whether it can be done succinctly within the same function.  I've explored using .startswith, rawstrings to add ^ and $ on the end of the complete lines, importing re.match (I couldn't iterate within the given code).

I think it might just be a beautiful dream, but can anyone think of an elegant way of doing this within the same pass?

Comment: Could you add some input/output to your question? It would be easier to understand what you mean by partial match.

Comment: added the two lists I'm using to test.  In this example, I want to delete all the newlines, and I want to remove:
"config", but NOT "config exclusive", and 
anything beginning with "config checkpoint" (including "config checkpoint test")

Comment: `listB = [line for line in listB if not line.startswith("config checkpoint") and not any(line in item for item in listA)]`?

Comment: unfortunately it needs to be fed from a list rather than as a simple string, since the list is generated from other functions depending on what the rest of the script is doing.  So for this example, "config checkpoint" is the string, but in other examples it could be multiple strings

Comment: I think you need to be more clear, because for example "config exclusive" starts with "config" but it is not removed, "config checkpoint test" starts with "config checkpoint" but it is removed. Why one is removed and the other one not? Why makes "config exclusive" (or "config") special?

Comment: well, that's the part that makes it complicated - how do I bake in the information?  It might be impossible, but I was hoping to be able to use regex as in listA = ["^config$", "^\n$", "^config checkpoint.*"]

Comment: Yes, but why the match for config is full and the match for config_checkpoint is different? How would anyone know that by just looking at two lists?

Comment: it's a valid point - it may improve clarity to have two different lists, one for full matches, one for partial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, `listA` is a list of regex patterns (as you wrote in comments), you can do:

```
import re

listA = ["^config$", "^\n$", "^config checkpoint"]
listB = ["config exclusive", "config checkpoint test", "config", "config", "config", "\n", "hello"]

listB = [line for line in listB if not any(re.match(item, line) for item in listA)]
print(listB)
```

**Output**

```
['config exclusive', 'hello']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [`difflib.get_close_matches`](https://khuyentran1401.github.io/Efficient_Python_tricks_and_tools_for_data_scientists/Chapter1/string.html#difflib-get-close-matches-get-a-list-of-the-best-matches-for-a-certain-word), that comes by default with Python.

**Example:**

```py
import difflib

listA = ["config", "\n", "config checkpoint"]
listB = ["config exclusive", "config checkpoint test", "config", "config", "config", "\n", "hello"]

new_listB = [line for line in listB if len(difflib.get_close_matches(line, listA, n=len(listA), cutoff=0.4)) == 0]
print(new_listB)
# Prints:
#
# ['hello']
```

#### Notes

The function `difflib.get_close_matches`, contains a parameter named `cutoff`. This parameter accepts values between 0 and 1 and is equal to 0.6 by default. The ideia here is that the lower you set this `cutoff` parameter, the lesser strict the function will be when trying to find elements from `listA` that match `line`. Here's an example:

```py
difflib.get_close_matches('John', ['John', 'Joe', 'Jane', 'Janet'], cutoff=0.2, n=100)
# Returns:
#
# ['John', 'Joe', 'Jane', 'Janet']

difflib.get_close_matches('John', ['John', 'Joe', 'Jane', 'Janet'], cutoff=0.6, n=100)
# Returns:
#
# ['John']
```

Comment: This is interesting, I don't think that's what I'm after, but I'll definitely read up on it

Comment: @Soop can you provide the desired output to you question?